# disable no-more-sessions@openssh.com on ssh

Tags: ssh

When I connect with ssh, i find that the "no-more-sessions@openssh.com" option is sent to sshd. Is there a way to disable it? I do want to have more sessions.

Answer (score 1):

This option is sent when session multiplexing is disabled, enable it if its really what you want. There's a guide on [multiplexing here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/speed-multiple-ssh-connections-same-server).